# tensorflow does not train RNN variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

For a complex text classification task I am training an RNN model. Somehow the weights of the RNN only change at the beginning and then with very tiny steps (gradients are in the range of e^-7):
[image: tensorboard]
For those of you who are not familiar with tensorboard: This shows the distribution of values for the bias and the weights of the RNN (x axis is the value, y axis the number of values and z the training iterations).

I constructed a toy example which does not make sense but reproduces the same behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tensorboard_save_path = "../RNN/tensorboard/supersimple/"

x = np.random.normal(size=(33, 20, 5000))
y = np.array([1 if i>0.5 else 0 for i in np.random.random(33)])


##### NETWORK #########
with tf.name_scope("RNN"):
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(1)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype=tf.float64)
    rnn_weights, rnn_biases = rnn_cell.variables
    tf.summary.histogram("RNN weights", rnn_weights)
    tf.summary.histogram("RNN biases", rnn_biases)

pred = tf.sigmoid(outputs[:,-1])

with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=pred, labels=np.reshape(y, (33,1)))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(tensorboard_save_path)
print("\ttensorboard --logdir=" + tensorboard_save_path)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run([optimizer])
    if i % 50 == 0:
        c, s = sess.run([cost, merged_summary])
        writer.add_summary(s, i)
        print("cost is %f" % c)
```

Expected behaviour would be that the model overfits due to the huge amount of variables in contrast to the few training samples. Any idea what's going wrong here?